# Pandas read_csv method only reading the first character of a csv cell value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file in Pandas. The first row values of the first 2 columns of the csv file are: CAR1590943902103952, '30492220204313540

However when I tried to read the csv:

```py
df=pd.read_csv('csv_ALL20200624.csv',encoding='iso-8859-1')
df.head()
```

I get the first two cell values as only 'C' and ', this is same for all the values in the columns. I have tried multiple encodings such as ANSI, utf-8 etc. but with no avail. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with python confusing the data types; try declaring the column as whatever datatype you want for that column.

Go here to read more about read_csv

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

These are the possible parameters for read_csv.

```
pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer: Union[str, pathlib.Path, IO[~ AnyStr]], sep=',', delimiter=None, header='infer', names=None, index_col=None, usecols=None, squeeze=False, prefix=None, mangle_dupe_cols=True, dtype=None, engine=None, converters=None, true_values=None, false_values=None, skipinitialspace=False, skiprows=None, skipfooter=0, nrows=None, na_values=None, keep_default_na=True, na_filter=True, verbose=False, skip_blank_lines=True, parse_dates=False, infer_datetime_format=False, keep_date_col=False, date_parser=None, dayfirst=False, cache_dates=True, iterator=False, chunksize=None, compression='infer', thousands=None, decimal: str = '.', lineterminator=None, quotechar='"', quoting=0, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, comment=None, encoding=None, dialect=None, error_bad_lines=True, warn_bad_lines=True, delim_whitespace=False, low_memory=True, memory_map=False, float_precision=None)
```

Comment: Interestingly the same code is now working properly. But, I am facing another issue. Whenever I am trying to change data type of a column to float, it is showing the following value error: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: " '0.25" " even though I have replaced the " ' " with " " in that column. What could be the problem here?

Comment: inspect the entire column to ensure all the values are numbers in character form. You might have weird values in the column messing everything up. Also run str.strip() to remove any leading and trailing white spaces; you can also do that in the read_csv step I think.

Comment: df['column_name'].replace(" ' ",' ',regex=True,inplace = True) has solved the problem